# Alamofire でファイルダウンロードの進捗を知りたい

Tags: swift, ios

ファイルダウンロードの進捗を知りたいので、
以下の様なコードを書いたのですが

```
Alamofire.download(request, to: destination)
    .progress { bytes, totalBytes, totalBytesExpected in
         print("progress")
    }
    .response { response in
        if response.error == nil, let path = response.destinationURL?.path {
            // DL成功
            print("success - movie download")
        } else {
           // DL失敗
           print("error - movie download")
        }
    }
```

.progress { bytes, totalBytes, totalBytesExpected in
の所で以下のエラーが出てしまいます。
「Cannot call value of non-function type 'Progress'」
解決方法をご存知の方、おられましたら、
ご教授願えませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の様に実装することで対応出来ました。

```
Alamofire.download(request, to: destination)
    .downloadProgress { progress in
         print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
         self.movieDownloadProgressBar.progress =　Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
    }    
　　.response { response in
        if response.error == nil, let path = response.destinationURL?.path {
            // DL成功
            print("success - movie download")
        } else {
           // DL失敗
           print("error - movie download")
        }
    }
```